# how do i replace a character in a string by range?

Tags: python, string

For example:

```
url = 'www.google.com/bla.bla'
```

I need to replace '.' with '' in the last 7 characters 
==> 'www.google.com/blabla'

I have tried :

```
for i in range(15,22):
   if url[i]=='.':
       url = url.replace('.', "")
```

But i get this error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 6):

A more *generic approach* would be to *split* the URL, replace the dot and then *join*:

```
In [1]: url = 'www.google.com/bla.bla'

In [2]: s = url.split("/")

In [3]: s[1] = s[1].replace(".", "")

In [4]: "/".join(s)
Out[4]: 'www.google.com/blabla'
```

Comment: might want `split("/",1)` ... not sure

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Even better, `str.partition('/')` will only split once and won't choke with an `IndexError` if the URL is a plain domain without a path: `domain, sep, path = url.partition('/')`, `newurl = domain + sep + path.replace('.', '')`, which handles both `www.google.com/bla.bla` and `www.google.com` without issue. When there is no path, `sep` and `path` are still the empty string, where `split` would return a length 1 `list` and explode when you asked for index `1`.

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

```
url = url[:-7] + (url[-7:].replace('.', ''))
```

Comment: What if it is not `bla.bla`, but `bla.bla.bla.bla`?

Comment: @alecxe `url = url[:15] + (url[15:].replace('.', ''))`    This is assuming we always start with www.google.com, though.  I agree that your soulution is the best

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `if` line since a single `=` is for assignment not comparison:

```
if url[i] == '.':
```

And note then when using `replace()` you will need to update the original string (`url`) since `replace()` will return a new string, not update the existing string.

However, I think **@Patrick Haugh's** one line answer is the better solution, though I would modify it as follows (if you are always using a google address):

```
url = url[:15] + url[15:].replace('.', '')
```

Comment: my mistake, i get the error after compiling it the way you said, i retyped the script wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Patrick for pointing out the flaw in my previous answer.

---

Instead of using `range()`, just use list comprehension and string indices:

```
url = 'www.google.com/bla.bla'
url = url[:15] + ''.join([c for c in url[15:] if c!= '.'])
```

Explanation.

- `url =`: reassign the value of url to...
- `url[:15]`: all the characters in `url` before the last seven...
- `+`: plus..
- `''.join([c for c in url[15:] if c!= '.'])`: the last seven characters in the string `url`, **only if** the value is not a `.`. Then join the list of characters together into a string.

After being modified the value of url will be: `'www.google.com/blabla'`

`print("Hello World") #keywords such as and or as are still highlighted`

Comment: This will replace all periods, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to test it. I have modified my answer accordingly.